# How can I combine GROUP_CONCAT and LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table animals:

```
╔══════════╦══════╗
║  animal  ║ id   ║
╠══════════╬══════╣
║   dog    ║ 1    ║
║   cat    ║ 4    ║
║   cat    ║ 3    ║
║  bird    ║ 1    ║
╚══════════╩══════╝
```

This is my table names:

```
╔═══════╦══════╗
║  id2  ║ name ║
╠═══════╬══════╣
║   1   ║ alan ║
║   2   ║ bob  ║
║   3   ║ john ║
║   4   ║ sam  ║
╚═══════╩══════╝
```

This is my expected result:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╗
║   dog    ║ alan        ║
║   cat    ║ sam,john    ║
║  bird    ║ alan        ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I tried this solution:

```
   $sql = '
     SELECT n.*, 
     x.grouped_name FROM names n 
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(a.animals) AS grouped_name FROM animals a GROUP BY a.id) x 
     ON x.id = n.id2';

     foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
          echo '<td>'.$row['animal'].' </td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row['grouped_name'].' </td>'; 
     }
```

But I do not get a result.

I also tried this solution:

```
$sql = ' SELECT n.*, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.id) FROM animals a WHERE a.id = n.id2) AS grouped_name FROM names n';
```

But my result is this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════╗
║          ║ 1,1         ║
║          ║ 3           ║
║          ║ 4           ║
╚══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.animal, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.name, "") separator ',') AS grouped_name
FROM animals t1
LEFT JOIN names t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id2
GROUP BY t1.animal
```

Have a look at the Fiddle to see the behavior when an animal does not match to anyone in the `names` table.  To handle this case, I use `COALESCE()` on the name to replace a `NULL` value by an empty string before group concatenating.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I tried to test your code on my php page and get an empty white page: `$sql = 'SELECT t1.animal, GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.name, "") separator ',')
FROM animals t1
LEFT JOIN names t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id2
GROUP BY t1.animal';`

Comment: Check the aliases which your PHP script is expecting.  The query runs fine in MySQL.

Comment: There must be a conflict with `separator ','` I tried to write instead `separator ","` or `separator '","'` but still not working

Comment: Remove `separator` entirely, i.e. use this: `GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(t2.name, "")) AS grouped_name`

Comment: The default separator should be comma anyway.  I believe this is an escaping problem in your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can use these query

```
select a.animal,group_concat(n.name) as name from animals as a 
LEFT JOIN name as n ON n.id2 = a.id
group by a.animal
```